# kubuntu 16.04 locks-creen slideshow

Tags: kubuntu, kde, lock-screen, plasma-5, slideshow

I remember being able to do that in kubuntu 14.04, is there a way to do that in 16.04? I found how to change the background image, but this is not a sideshow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**KDE plasma 5 lock screen**

By Martin Gräßlin - Animations on lock screen – Plasma Wallpaper support: https://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2016/07/animations-on-lock-screen-plasma-wallpaper-support/

> ... Today I’m happy to announce that this situation is going to change
>   with Plasma 5.8. Our lock screen architecture gained support for
>   Plasma Wallpaper plugins. All the wallpaper plugins available for the
>   desktop are now also available for the lock screen...

With the Plasma 5.8:
[image]

Meanwhile, with the earlier plasma versions:

- Lock screen with picture slideshow: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?67703-Kubuntu-video-wallpaper&p=388438&viewfull=1#post388438
- an animated background for the lock screen?: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?67703-Kubuntu-video-wallpaper&p=382459&viewfull=1#post382459
- KDE Plasma 5 editing logout and lock screens: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?67703-Kubuntu-video-wallpaper&p=382534&viewfull=1#post382534